# Isolating USB3 with an ADUM4160

Tags: usb, isolation, instrumentation

I've not played with USB much besides the ordinary FTDI UART bridges. Recently, I have reason to use an FT601 with a USB3 port configured for super-speed operation. As this is connected to a fairly high-performance instrument (24-bit ADCs are present), I would like to isolate the USB interface from the rest of the circuit.

The ADUM4160 seems to be a handy isolator circuit, but is only available for USB1.1 12Mbps operation. However, as the superspeed lines on USB3 are capacitavely-coupled differential siganls anyhow, this seems OK for isolating DP/DM.

In the USB3 specification, it seems that DP/DM are compatible with the USB2 PHY, and SSTX/SSRX are capacitively isolated anyways. However, the isolator will not be able to keep up with 480Mbps USB2 operation.

Is there any reason to suspect that the ADUM4160 would be unable to isolate USB3? In handshaking up to superspeed operation, will DP/DM operate faster than 12Mbps?

Circuit sketch here:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Coupling via a Capacitor is not the same as electrical isolation. You need to think about your ground return path aswell!

There are also reasons, why a part search on DigiKey/Mouser doesnt really show ready made solutions for USB3 isolation.

The common approach is to isolate your application from the interface, and not the interface from the application. Sounds akward? See the Figure.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB8NIq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As far as i understand your application, i would isolate the ADCs from the MCU/FPGA and communicate via a SPI-Bus (Can have multiple in parallel, or have a FPGA on the other side to time-multiplex multiple ADC<->FPGA connections into a single high-speed FPGA <->ISO<->MCU connection) with them. This allows you to not have to isolate the USB interface and keeps digital noise out of the analog isolated side.

Comment: missed that USB3 is not a current-mode output - i'm used to LVDS or AC-coupled CML at these speeds. that's bloody annoying

Answer (score 1):

The USB2 lines are not used at all for USB3 handshake and USB3 is tried first.

But if you think you can just leave the pins capacitively floating without ground reference, it will be the wrong solution.

Imagine an ESD even which suddenly makes one device ground rise by few hundred volts, the poor USB3 AC coupling caps cannot instantly change by the few hundred volts as there needs to be a current through them for voltage to develop over them. This will kill the USB3 interface.

Your proposed circuit will also fail to work properly as there are 33 ohm resistors on supply return wire.

Perhaps if you described why or from what problems you think the isolation would protect from, there may be other solutions. You can ask another question about that.

Comment: Thanks for the USB2/USB3 clarification.

I don't really care much about ESD - this isn't DFM, it's not going to leave the bench.

Good point about C coupling. I have my head stuck in CML output stages for SpaceFibre - I try to avoid USB when I can. Annoying that it's not a current-mode output stage in the PHY. The 33Rs are a copy-paste job so I can isolate later.

Comment: @instrumental It's also not just about ESD. If you e.g. have grounded PC and your instrument uses ungrounded 2-prong supply, the ungrounded device could float tens of volts in respect to the grounded PC. What is the motivation of isolating the instrument from PC to begin with?

Comment: Good point. The supply is a doubly-isolated converter with a bonding strap to chassis, which is wired to the primary-side star point, which is in turn connected to local earth - so things should be close in potential. I have quite a sensitive analogue chain with very fast readout (~100ksps 24-bit) on top of an 18-bit 30MSPS imaging readout. I need to connect to a PC for readout but want to avoid coupling noise from the PC into the measurement. Ideally I'd use an LVDS/CML standard with isolators but there's no room for the right PCI cards in the budget at the moment :-(.

Comment: If your instrument is anyway earthed, there should be no need for isolation if you connect it to an already earthed desktop PC, or battery powered laptop, or in a pinch, to a laptop with isolated supply that has only a weak or no bonding to earth at all. If there is any interference, isolating the USB would only be a workaround for the underlying problem. USB3 isolators do exist, but then you still need to power both the PC and instrument end somehow, a mains supply or isolated DC converter, so anyway possible noise sources.

Comment: perhaps I'm just being overly pedantic then :-). many thanks for your help!